# MassTransit registering multiple Consumers of the same message type

Tags: c#, azure, masstransit

I'm having a a little issue understanding what is happening with MassTransit and Azure when you **publish** a message rather than **Send** it.

Basically I have an Action of DownloadWebpage and an Event of WebPageDownloaded. In the consumer for the DownloadWebpage I Publish an event of WebPageDownloaded and I would like multiple subscribers to that event to be able to consume that notification.

But I can't register multiple Consumers for the event using the same queue name. For example the following code, will give an exception when it tries to register the second consumer of the WebpageDownloaded event.

```
configurator.ReceiveEndpoint("downloadwebpage", e => e.Consumer<DownloadPageConsumer>());
configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "webpagedownloaded", e => e.Consumer<WebPageDownloadedConsumer>());
configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "webpagedownloaded", e => e.Consumer<WebPageDownloadedConsumer02>());
```

However the following will work when I don't specify a receive queue name.

```
configurator.ReceiveEndpoint("downloadwebpage", e => e.Consumer<DownloadPageConsumer>());
configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(host, e => e.Consumer<WebPageDownloadedConsumer>());
configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(host, e => e.Consumer<WebPageDownloadedConsumer02>());
```

But then messages don't seem to persist between runs.

**UPDATE** I've just found the event messages move to a dead letter queue when the bus is stopped. E.g. I start the service and send a message, which when consumed publishes an event. The event listeners pick this up and all works OK. 
I then stop the service, I don't register the event consumers, I send a message and publish the event. The events are waiting to be processed (I can see them in what looks like a temporary queue in Azure) but as soon as I stop the bus, they immediately move to a dead letter queue. I had though they would be persisted there for a service to pick them up in the future, and timeout after the Time To Live and then move to a dead letter queue.

Anyone any idea of where I am going wrong, I know I'm just missing some level of understanding, but just can't see to find out what I don't know.

Comment: OK Folks, I might be on to something, I completely missed the configurator.SubscriptionEndpoint, looking into that at the moment.

Comment: If you need further help please update the question. You can have multiple consumers on receive endpoints, but the receive endpoints each need unique queue names.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the update, I've have a working example together now. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -4):

I figured out what I needed on the receive endpoints and also by using subscriptions also for topic style messages.